# How to call same JQuery function on click of elements having same ids

Tags: jquery

I Have many elements having same is but with different data,I want to call same JQuery function on click of each element.How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have multiple ID's in your HTML markup.

It would be an invalid markup. When querying for `$('#foobar')` and there are five elements which have that id, you would only get the first instance. So even if there would be a way (...) to apply code to all of those nodes, *don't do it*.

Use *Classnames* when you want to "combine" some elements.

Answer (score 6):

Using the same ID on more than one element is not allowed. Use classes for that.

```
<div class="myClass">..</div>
<div class="myClass">..</div>

$(".myClass").click(function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
jQuery ("div,span,p.myClass").click(function() {

//your code
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

When operating with id's can create lot of redundancy it is better to operate with classes but if your classes are getting repeated than it could be a bit tricky to handle i would recommend you to use some custom attributes for this

Some sample code for you.

```
    var spnActive = document.createElement("span");
    $(spnActive).attr('isExpColSpan', 'true');
    $('#dvContainer').find('span[isExpColSpan="true"]').
```

In the second line i have added an custom attribute in the next line i have shown how to use this attribute.